# How to delete a Formula field(text) that uses an image in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public with sharing class WebService {

    public Account acc;

    public WebService(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            stdController.addFields(new List<String>{'Any_Account_Field__c'});
        }
        this.acc = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        System.debug('account name' + this.acc.Any_Account_Field__c);

    }

    public PageReference sendStructure {

        //To delete the 'Any_Account_Field__c' which is a formula field(text) that 
        //uses an image.
        this.callOut(this.acc.Id);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have my visualforce extension as Webservice and I have a requirement to delete the field 'Any_Account_Field__c' which is referencing the account. But I am not sure how I can achieve this. Could some one help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was confused by the fact that your Visualforce controller is named `WebService`, which is an Apex keyword, but I see that it's not actually implementing a web service. Why do you need to alter the database schema from Visualforce? You cannot do so without making a Metadata API callout, which most users don't have permission to do.

Comment: The scenario is to delete the old custom field entries before doing the call out. But can you tell how do we delete such field records, I mean the formula field(text) fields which uses a image field ?

Comment: Let's be clear about what you are trying to do. Are you trying to *delete a field definition from your entire database*, *remove the value in a formula field on one record in the database*, or *clear a value from an sObject variable you want to send in a callout*? These are very different tasks.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the value in a formula field on one record in the database before I do the callOut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, you want to

> remove the value in a formula field on one record in the database before I do the callOut

Formula fields are always read-only. You cannot affect its value directly in the database. Your only options are

1. Change the values of the fields, if any, that are referenced by this formula field in a way that results in the formula rendering a blank value. This is specific to the formula itself, and not all formulas can be blanked at all.
2. Change the way you are calling your web service so that you provide an sObject variable in Apex. Then, in Apex, simply don't query the value of the formula field `Any_Account_Field__c`. Alternately, change the query in your `callOut()` method to omit this field from the query.